# recursive printing of tree structure from XML having strange behavior in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, recursion, vtd-xml

I'm reading in an XML file and recreating the structure for reprinting minus all attributes, values, and text.  It's working fine as far as I can tell, but when I try to reprint it in the console I get very strange behavior.

```
for( xmlNode n : treeNodes )
    {
        System.out.println( n.getLabel() );
        printChildNodes( n, 1 );
    }


private static void printChildNodes( xmlNode n, int indent )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < indent; i++ )
    {
        System.out.print( indent );
    }

    for( xmlNode child : n.getChildren() )
    {
        System.out.println( child.getLabel() + " " + indent );
        printChildNodes( child, indent+1 );
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
ROOT
1A 1
22B 2
333C 3
4444D 4
55555E 5
666666D 4
55555E 5
666666D 4
55555E 5
666666D 4
```

Originally instead of indent I was printing "\t" but I noticed the structure looked wrong.  Now I'm scratching my head as to what possible ghost in the machine is resulting in my "indent" variable having two separate values with no changes made to it.  Not to mention that the oddities are somewhat predictable.  D elements should be to the left of E not to the right (since they are parents of E).

Any ideas?

Comment: How does the xml look like ? and the getLabel() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only print the "indent" (actually a lot of numerics) once, at the start of the node's first line.

You then print children with a newline after each. The "indent" will only precede the first child.

You also don't print the *node itself* you are visiting, but only print the *children*. This is erroneous, and what with the node itself not showing up/ just a spurious indent, output will be very confusing when there are no children.

Additionally, you iterate over `treeNodes` and call into the `printChildNodes` function -- but that is recursive. Ideally I would only expect *one* recursive function to print & descend the entire subtree, with no loop.

```
printTree( rootNode, 0);

private static void printTree (xmlNode n, int indent) {
    StringBuilder ind = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
        ind.append(' ');

    // print the Node;
    //
    System.out.println( ind + n.getLabel());

    // traverse Descendants.
    //
    for (xmlNode child : n.getChildren()) {
        printTree( child, indent+1);
    }
}
```

This should be pretty foolproof.

Comment: I print the root node before entering the recursive function since for now my tree has only a single root node with children.  I'm printing numbers to double check that the right number of indents are being sent since when I was printing "\t" it was not looking correct compared to the original XML.  I'll try your code but I'm not understanding how I'm ending up with "indent" printing different  values on the same line in the same function.

Comment: Your posted code would print an indent but no label, and leave the line incomplete, for a leaf node with no children. **Subsequent nodes will then print following this on the same line.** The posted code labels the nodes in the wrong place & doesn't firmly correlate printing of indents with the node labels. Of course it's going to produce erroneous or confusing output.

Comment: Ah I see now after testing and playing with it.  Thank you